# Multiplying a char with the amount of next integer

Tags: c

Before i begin,This is my first question,English isn't my first language and i am a newbie at C Programming.I searched my question but couldn't found.My question is that how do i print the times of next integer in a string.

For Example : input  :      a2b3d4e5fgh
              output :      aabbbddddeeeeefgh

Thanks.

EDIT : The real task is that there is a string with maximum 30 characters,when there is only strings with characters it just prints the input but when there is a character part with ' separated it must involve characters and integers and the characters must be printed with the amount of the next integer.

Sample Input 1:

```
abcdefg
```

Sample Output 1:

```
abcdefg
```

Sample Input 2:

```
'a2b3c2d2'efg
```

Sample Output 2:

```
aabbbccddefg
```

I am here

```
int main () {

    char number[30];
    scanf("%s", &number);
    char *part1 = strtok(number, "'");
    char *part2 = strtok(NULL, "'");
    char *part3 = strtok(NULL, "'");


    /*if (number[30]!=0){
        printf("Falsche Eingabe");
    } */





    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: My curiosity is killing me: what happens with `a11b4c5de` ? Is there one `a` or eleven in the final output string ? Regardless, it's starts with an *algorithm*, then some code. We somewhat have the former, and nothing of the latter, so refining both and *trying* is on your agenda. After doing so, if things aren't right, you've tried debugging your code, and still are stuck, bring it here and we can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

For sure this question require some concentration. I'm not good at C, but I can present a certain logic that can be used to achieve this. I will provide also a java code sample that I'm sure can be easily translated into C.

1. Have initialize your string, either from user input or with a default value:

`String data = "m3bdfg21tehy4h"; String newData="";`

2. Declare a variable that will store the last non-digit character position, let's assume the first character must be an alphabetic:

`int lastNonDigitPosition=0;`

3. Declare a boolean variable that will let you know the last verified character is digit or non-digit:

`Boolean isLastCharDigit=false;`

4. Declare a variable that will store digits sequence if we can have more than 1 digit at a time:

`String digitSequence="";`

5. Transform the String/CharSequence into an array of characters
   `char[] chars=data.toString().toCharArray();`
6. verify every character at a given position

```java
for (int i=0;i<chars.length;i++)
                    {
                      //verify is the current character is not digit
                        if (!Character.isDigit(chars[i]))
                        {

                            if (isLastCharDigit)
                            {
                            /*If the last char was a digit, cast the value of digitSequence to integer so you can know how many times you will repeat the character that comes before digit sequence*/
                                int digitTimes=Integer.valueOf(digitSequence);

                                //reinitialize the digit sequence 

                                digitSequence="";
                                for (int j=0;j<digitTimes;j++)
                                {
                                //concatenate the last non-digit character to newData digitTimes times 
                                    newData+=chars[lastNonDigitPosition];
                                }
                            }else{
                            //if the last char was not a digit just a the character to the String
                                newData+=chars[i];
                            }

                            //save the last non-digit position
                            lastNonDigitPosition=i;
                            //inform this current character is not digit
                            isLastCharDigit=false;

                        }else{
                           //if the character is a digit, concatenate with //digitSequence and inform the last char is digit
                            digitSequence+=chars[i];
                            isLastCharDigit=true;
                        }
                    }
```

This is how I could solve the issue. This is JAVA sample if someone can translate into C that can be good, I tried to explain the logic to make the code more understandable.